# How to add multiple objects to multiple collections?

Tags: collections

I have about 50 objects I want to have in 3 different collections. How do I do this quickly without having to do this individually for each object? So for example I have 50 cubes and I have collection1, collection2 and collection3. How do I set them all at once to be on those 3 collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all your cubes (if your cubes share the same mesh you can select them with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> *(Select Similar) > Object Data*), then to put them in a collection press <kbd>M</kbd>, and to put them in another collection as well, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> *(Link to Collection)* and choose or create the collection, and so on for the other collections. The objects will be shared by these collections.

If you select an object and press <kbd>X</kbd> it will be deleted from all the collections. If you select it in a collection in the *Outliner* and right click > *Unlink*, it will only be removed from this collection.

Comment: Thanks! I knew of m but didn't think of shift-m. Linking to collection sounded something different than I previously thought but now I know better.